# How to set the quality of the picture when using the expo camera?

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-camera

I'm using **Expo** (React Native) and **Express.js** (Node.js) and I'm trying to develop an app that can take pictures and store them on the server.

So far, I have completed all this, but I want to make sure the server isn't overrun from really high quality photos that smartphones can take nowadays.

I tried to look at the documentation for the Expo camera and there is a section for quality, but it's under the `CameraPictureOptions` which is under the `Types` section.

I'm not 100% sure how to access these in the code as they don't offer any examples. Really all I need is an example of how to edit the quality of the photos that the Expo camera takes.

Comment: Please check my posted answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `expo-camera` captured picture quality by using `quality: 0.5,` in the `takePictureAsync` options

```
 const photo = await cameraRef.takePictureAsync({
    quality: 0.5, // Adjust this value (0.0 - 1.0) for picture quality
    skipProcessing: true, // Set to true to skip processing
 });
```

`skipProcessing` is not related to the question but this to faster the camera capture

Comment: If you add skipProcessing it will ignore the quality setting. https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/